# Calculate the cardinalities of all disjoint subsets from cardinalities of unions

Tags: python, set

Suppose that I have two sets A and B and I know their cardinalities |A| and |B| as well as the cardinality of their union |A U B|. Then there are three disjoint subsets A \ B, B \ A and A ∩ B. Their cardinalities are

- |A \ B| = |A U B| - |B|,
- |B \ A| = |A U B| - |A| and
- |A ∩ B| = |A| + |B| - |A U B|.

If I have three sets A, B and C then the corresponding expressions are

- |A \ (B U C)| = |A U B U C| - |B U C|
- |A ∩ B ∩ C)| = |A U B U C| + |A| + |B| + |C| - |A U B| - |A U C| - |B U C|
- |(A ∩ B) \ C)| = |A U C| + |B U C| - |A U B U C| - |C|
- ... (the rest can be found by renaming A, B and C)

However, I can't find a good algorithm for calculating the same thing for an arbitrary amount of sets A, B, C,...

So my question is, is there some useful algorithm to do this?

Here is some code that produces an example set of unions that can be used to try things out.

```py
import numpy as np
from string import ascii_uppercase
from itertools import combinations
from collections import defaultdict

def build_example(k):
    '''Produces an example collection of unions with and the sought after disjoint subsets as key.'''
    # Produce data in the disjoint subsets that will later be used as key
    n_disjoint_subsets = 2**k - 1
    set_ids = np.arange(n_disjoint_subsets).reshape(-1, 1) + 1
    in_set = np.unpackbits(set_ids.astype(np.uint8), axis=1)[:, -k:] == 1
    disjoint_counts = np.random.randint(0, 10, n_disjoint_subsets)
    set_names = np.array([
        set_name for set_name, _ in zip(ascii_uppercase, range(k))
    ], dtype=object)
    key = np.hstack([in_set.astype(int), disjoint_counts.reshape(-1, 1)])

    # Produce the unions
    unions = defaultdict(int)
    for r in range(1, k + 1):
        for indices in combinations(range(k), r):
            indices = np.array(indices)
            mask = in_set[:, indices].any(axis=1)
            name = " U ".join(set_names[indices])
            unions[name] = disjoint_counts[mask].sum()
    
    return unions, key
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that the problem could be written as a system of linear equations.

Identify each disjoint subset by which base set (A, B, C,...) it is contained in such that |(A ∩ C) \ B| is identified by the boolean values (1, 0, 1) and each union of subsets by which base sets are its constituents such that |A U C| is identified by (1, 0, 1) as well.

Then to build the equation system realise that a union U identified by (b1, b2, ...) is U = c1 D1 + c2 D2 + ... where Di is count of subset with ID(Di) and ci is 1 if any(ID(Di) & ID(U)) and 0 otherwise.

Here is the code that solves it

```py
def calculate_subsets(unions):
    set_names = np.unique(np.hstack(
        [union_name.split(" U ") for union_name in unions]
    ))
    k = len(set_names)
    n_disjoint_subsets = 2**k - 1
    set_ids = np.arange(n_disjoint_subsets).reshape(-1, 1) + 1
    in_set = np.unpackbits(np.fliplr(set_ids.view(np.uint8)), axis=1)[:, -k:] == 1

    # Build system of linear equations
    system = np.zeros(2 * [n_disjoint_subsets], dtype=int)
    for i_row, union_name in enumerate(unions):
        union_id = np.array([name in union_name for name in set_names])
        system[i_row, :] = (union_id & in_set).any(axis=1) 
    
    union_values = np.array(list(unions.values()))
    disjoint_counts = np.linalg.solve(system, union_values).astype(int)
    
    disjoint_subsets = np.hstack([in_set, disjoint_counts.reshape(-1, 1)])
    return disjoint_subsets
```